# Error using decision tree regressor

Tags: decision-trees, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

I'm new to data science , while i'm implementing decision tree. I'm facing the following error. Where i went wrong;

Sample data in csv is:
[image]

```py
x=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,:2].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
labelencoder_x=LabelEncoder()
x[:,0]=labelencoder_x.fit_transform(x[:,0])
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder()
columntransformer=ColumnTransformer([('dummy cols',onehotencoder,[0])],remainder='passthrough')
x=columntransformer.fit_transform(x)


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=1)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
regressor=DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)
regressor.fit(x,y)  #Error occurance
```

Error:
'''
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Business Analyst'
'''

Comment: You haven't included details of the error you're experiencing

Comment: @DanScally thanks for reminding. I forgot to embed it. I have updated it.

Comment: Which line gives you this error ?

Comment: @ashukid regressor.fit() is giving me the error

Comment: You have strings values in `x` when you call `regressor.fit(x,y)`. All values need to be float or int

Comment: @SimonLarsson But im using the column transformer which does the job of encoding categorical variable and returns float

Comment: The string values are in you `y` variable. Try doing `print(y)` before calling fit and you will see it.

Comment: @SimonLarsson here is what i get when i print x                                                            (0, 0)        1.0
  (0, 10)       1.0
  (1, 4)        1.0
  (1, 10)       2.0
  (2, 8)        1.0
  (2, 10)       3.0
  (3, 5)        1.0
  (3, 10)       4.0
  (4, 3)        1.0
  (4, 10)       5.0
  (5, 7)        1.0
  (5, 10)       6.0
  (6, 6)        1.0
  (6, 10)       7.0
  (7, 9)        1.0
  (7, 10)       8.0
  (8, 1)        1.0
  (8, 10)       9.0
  (9, 2)        1.0
  (9, 10)       10.0

Comment: I saw, print `y` instead.

Comment: @SimonLarsson Got it, Thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the **y** value.

```
x=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values -> selecting all columns but last #this one is fine

y=dataset.iloc[:,:2].values -> selecting all columns till 2nd #this one is wrong
```

Change this to :

```
y=dataset.iloc[:,2].values #selecting only 2nd column.
```